# How to deploy gRPC server/client to heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, grpc

I deployed my python gRPC server to Heroku and was wondering how I could test it with a local Python client.

*server.py*

```
def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    icp_pb2_grpc.add_MyServicer_to_server(MyServicer(), server)

    server_port = os.environ.get('PORT', 50051) 
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:'+ str(server_port))
    server.start()
    print("==== SERVER RUNNING =====")
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()
```

*client.py*

```
def run():
    # Is the channel url correct?
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('https://www.HEROKUURL.com:50051')
    stub = my_grpc.MyStub(channel)
    file = _get_file_content()
    response = stub.Predict(icp_pb2.MyRequest(file_content=file))
    print("received: " + response.results)
```

I am using the client from my computer and am not receiving any response from the server. I am able to successfully communicate with the server if it is launched locally. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How certain are you that gRPC is involved in the problem? Have you run an ordinary HTTP server in your Heroku environment and been able to connect to it?

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle Pretty certain, I was able to successfully communicate with an ordinary server. The gRPC app was also working perfectly locally. It's not that there's an issue with gRPC, I'm just not exactly sure how to deploy it and connect to the server.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku [does not support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#http-versions-supported) HTTP 2. On the other hand, GRPC uses a `http/2` based transport. I think that's why you can connect it locally but not from Heroku.